# Invoke-ProcessTable : The provided application id is invalid

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, invoke-command, azure-analysis-services

This is what I've got in my [Invoke-ProcessTable powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-processtable?view=sqlserver-ps) script (snippet)

```
# create pscredential object
$credObject = New-Object    -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
                            -ArgumentList $ServicePrincipal, $secStringPassword

#Get App Id for Service Principle
$SPDetails = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $ServicePrincipal 
$SP_AppId   = ($SPDetails).AppId

Invoke-ProcessTable `
    -TableName $TableName `
    -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
    -RefreshType Full `
    -Server  $Server `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -Credential $credObject `
    -TenantId $TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $SP_AppId
```

$TenantId is hard coded in the script.

[image]

and this is the error I'm getting

> Invoke-ProcessTable : The provided application id 'app:"service
> principle name"@6"tenant id"5' is invalid. Parameter name: id At
> C:\temp\powerrshell\invoke-processtable.ps1:25 char:1
>
> - Invoke-ProcessTable `
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ProcessTable], ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessTable
>   ```

I wasn't expecting the Application Id to be in the format that is being shown in the error message.
Anyway, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$SP_AppId = ($SPDetails).ApplicationId` ?

Comment: No, It's `($SPDetails).AppId` .

Answer (score 0):

School boy error

I was passing in the wrong parameter to the `$credObject` object

I was sending in the ServicePrincipleName (`$ServicePrincipal`) instead of the Application Id (`$SP_AppId`).

Once I did this all worked.

```
#Get App Id for Service Principle
$SPDetails = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $ServicePrincipal 
$SP_AppId   = ($SPDetails).AppId

# create pscredential object
$credObject = New-Object    -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
                            -ArgumentList $SP_AppId, $secStringPassword
```